# Fail to send two words as one parameter from android to WCF service

Tags: android, wcf

I'm very new to Android & WCF web service. I fail to send two words (James Bond) as a one a parameter from android to WCF service. If i send as JamesBond then it works.Can anyone expert in this language, guide me.Thanks.Below is the example:

Its not Working when i use space in the variable as follows

```
String name="James Bond"
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:3113/Service1.svc/getStatusDetails?name="+name);
```

Its working when there is no space in the variable

```
String name="JamesBond"
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:3113/Service1.svc/getStatusDetails?name="+name);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following way,

```
String name="James Bond";
name = name.replaceAll ( " ", "%20" );
HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:3113/Service1.svc/getStatusDetails?name="+name);
```

As spaces in the URL are not allowed you simply need to replace a space with `%20`

Comment: can i get your email address or anything.so easy for me to contact you if got any doubts.thanks again bro..

Comment: sorry, you can simply ask question, i will answer it if i am online during that time :)